# Rails 5: AJAX not triggering for save/load callbacks (PATCH / GET)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm a bit stuck in implementing AJAX with JSON response. I have this **Controller**

```
class Common::DatatablesStatesController < ApplicationController

  def update
    datatables_state.update(datatable_states_params)
    render json: datatables_state
  end

  def show
    render json: datatables_state
  end

  private
  def datatable_states_params
    params.require(:common_datatable_state).permit(:user_id, :name, :state)
  end

  def datatables_state
    @datatables_state ||= current_user.datatables_states
                          .where(name: params[:id]).first_or_create
  end
end
```

which basically checks if record by param exists if yes, then update `state` column, if no - creates new record (current_user ID, contname from JS below, state)

My **Coffeescript** at the moment looks like this:

```
$ ->
  $('#data-table').DataTable
    ajax: $('#data-table').data('source')
    serverSide: true
    stateSave: true
    contname = $('#data-table').attr('data-controller-name')
    'stateSaveCallback': (settings, data) ->
      $.ajax
        'url': '/common/datatables_states/' + contname + '.json'
        'data':
          'user_id': user_id
          'name': contname
          'state': data
        'dataType': 'json'
        'type': 'PATCH'
        success: ->
      return
    'stateLoadCallback': (settings, callback) ->
      $.ajax
        'url': '/common/datatables_states/' + contname + '.json'
        'data':
          'name': contname
          'state': data
        'async': false
        'dataType': 'json'
        'type': 'GET'
        'success': (json) ->
          callback json
          return
      return
  return
```

I'm pretty sure there is something wrong in my JS part as nothing is happening in my console, but don't know what it is. I'd be happy for any help. Thank you!

**Update**

My routes look like this:

```
namespace :common do
  resources :datatables_states, only: [:update, :show]
end
```

`rails routes`

```
 common_datatables_state GET    (/:locale)/common/datatables_states/:id(.:format)        common/datatables_states#show {:locale=>/en|lv/}
                                   PATCH  (/:locale)/common/datatables_states/:id(.:format)        common/datatables_states#update {:locale=>/en|lv/}
                                   PUT    (/:locale)/common/datatables_states/:id(.:format)        common/datatables_states#update {:locale=>/en|lv/}
```

Basically idea was to pass that `data-controller-name` from view as ID.

**Update2**

I switched to vanila JS as I had suspicion something's not right with my Coffeescript. Here is what I put in my JS file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data-table').DataTable(
            {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": $('#data-table').data('source'),
                stateSave: true,
                "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
                    // Send an Ajax request to the server with the state object
                    $.ajax( {
                        "url": "/common/datatables_states/campaigns_index.json", //Test link with :ID campaigns_index.json
                        "data": {"name":"campaigns_index", "state": data} ,
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "type": "PATCH",
                        "success": function () {}
                    } );
                },
                   stateLoadCallback: function (settings, callback) {
                      $.ajax( {
                         url: '/common/datatables_states/campaigns_index.json',
                         async: false,
                         dataType: 'json',
                         type: 'GET',
                         success: function (json) {
                         callback( json );
                         }
                    } );
                 }
            }
    );
});
```

and this is what I see in my console now:

```
Started PATCH "/common/datatables_states/campaigns_index.json" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-05-12 20:27:03 +0000
Processing by Common::DatatablesStatesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"name"=>"campaigns_index", "state"=>{"time"=>"1494620823501", "start"=>"0", "length"=>"10", "order"=>{"0"=>["0", "asc"]}, "search"=>{"search"=>"", "smart"=>"true", "regex"=>"false", "caseInsensitive"=>"true"}, "columns"=>{"0"=>{"visible"=>"true", "search"=>{"search"=>"", "smart"=>"true", "regex"=>"false", "caseInsensitive"=>"true"}}, "1"=>{"visible"=>"true", "search"=>{"search"=>"", "smart"=>"true", "regex"=>"false", "caseInsensitive"=>"true"}}, "2"=>{"visible"=>"true", "search"=>{"search"=>"", "smart"=>"true", "regex"=>"false", "caseInsensitive"=>"true"}}}}, "id"=>"campaigns_index"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Common::DatatableState Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "common_datatable_states".* FROM "common_datatable_states" WHERE "common_datatable_states"."user_id" = $1 AND "common_datatable_states"."name" = $2 ORDER BY "common_datatable_states"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 2], ["name", "campaigns_index"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)


ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: common_datatable_state):

app/controllers/common/datatables_states_controller.rb:14:in `datatable_states_params'
app/controllers/common/datatables_states_controller.rb:4:in `update'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:45:in `set_current_user'
```

**Update 3**

I'm trying to implement [stateLoadCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback) for my DataTables 1.10.13.

I changed my controller action to this so it selects `state` only:

```
def show
  state = current_user.datatables_states.where(name: params[:id]).select(:state)
  render json: state
end
```

then in JS I do this, which is kind of according to docs:

```
 stateLoadCallback: function (settings, callback) {
                      $.ajax( {
                         url: '/common/datatables_states/campaigns_index.json',
                         async: false,
                         dataType: 'json',
                         type: 'GET',
                         success: function (json) {
                         callback( json );
                         }
                    } );
                 }
```

however in terminal I do not get `state` back:

```
Started GET "/common/datatables_states/campaigns_index.json" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-05-14 10:02:03 +0000
Processing by Common::DatatablesStatesController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"campaigns_index"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Common::DatatableState Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "common_datatable_states"."state" FROM "common_datatable_states" WHERE "common_datatable_states"."user_id" = $1 AND "common_datatable_states"."name" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["name", "campaigns_index"]]
Completed 200 OK in 83ms (Views: 25.3ms | ActiveRecord: 9.6ms)
```

Type of my `state` column is JSON and when I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/en/common/datatables_states/campaigns_index.json` I see this:

```
[
  {
    "id": null,
    "state": "{\"time\":\"1494761473541\",\"start\":\"0\",\"length\":\"10\",\"order\":{\"0\":[\"0\",\"asc\"]},\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"},\"columns\":{\"0\":{\"visible\":\"true\",\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"}},\"1\":{\"visible\":\"true\",\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"}},\"2\":{\"visible\":\"true\",\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"}}}}"
  }
]
```

**Update 3.1.**

I added `state = current_user.datatables_states.where(name: params[:id]).select(:state).first`

and I have this now:

```
{
  "id": null,
  "state": "{\"time\":\"1494910215056\",\"start\":\"0\",\"length\":\"10\",\"order\":{\"0\":[\"0\",\"asc\"]},\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"},\"columns\":{\"0\":{\"visible\":\"true\",\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"}},\"1\":{\"visible\":\"true\",\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"}},\"2\":{\"visible\":\"true\",\"search\":{\"search\":\"\",\"smart\":\"true\",\"regex\":\"false\",\"caseInsensitive\":\"true\"}}}}"
}
```

When I change my `show` to this:

```
def show
  state = current_user.datatables_states.where(name: params[:id]).select(:state).first
  my_hash = JSON.parse(state)
  render json: JSON.pretty_generate(my_hash)
end
```

and get this error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
app/controllers/common/datatables_states_controller.rb:10:in `show'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:45:in `set_current_user'
```

**What should I do to get my stateLoadCallback working?**

Comment: Are you sure you set up your routes correctly? Can you post your `routes.rb` or result of calling `rake routes`?

Comment: @xlts Please, see in Update above.

Comment: @xlts Can you check my Update 2 above, please? I changed to vanila JS and now I start seeing something in my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you added indicates that no `common_datatable_state` parameter was passed, this is because of how you defined your strong parameters (`datatable_state_params` method). Try changing the `data` field in your ajax call like this:

```
"data": {"common_datatable_state":{"name":"campaigns_index", "state": data}}
```

Comment: Thank you, in general you are right and I'm accepting and upvoting. In my case I had to do `"data": {"common_datatable_state":{"user_id": "2", "name":"campaigns_index", "state": data}} ,`

Comment: Could you, please, check my Update 3 above, where I try to implement `show` method for getting back `state` data from DB.

Comment: Well, you can see the output so it's only a matter of debugging. First of all, you may want to call `.first` when selecting datatable states - right now you're returning an array and I suppose you should only end up with single object. As for the output, you can see it's a JSON packed in a string. You can try to call `JSON.parse(query_result)` to get a ruby hash which can be rendered as pretty json (see http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to follow your suggestion, however I get `TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String)` Can you check my Update 3.1. above, please? One more thing - shouldn't I be somehow getting rid of that `"id": null` somehow?

Comment: The error tells you that something on line 10 is nil - try to debug it e.g. with `pry` gem. To get rid of `"id": null` you should specify what you're serializing exactly. You can for example do `render json: { state: state["state"] }` or something in this fashion

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here `where(name: params[:id])` , could you check params here

Comment: What do you mean by checking params? Idea was to take that `data-controller-name` from view and pass it as `id` - please, see my routes in Update above.

Comment: Can you check my Update 2 above, please? I changed to vanila JS and now I start seeing something in my console.